# UIAlertView "Please Wait" and NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uialertview, wait

In my `ViewDidLoad` I call `UIAlertView` `"Getting data. Please Wait...."` and a `NSTimer`    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval 5 sec.
After this I create a method `GetData` with `NSURLConnection` to get data from a web server.
In `didFailWithError` of `NSURLConnection` I have another `UIAlertView`:

```
"Cannot connect to server. Please check your network settings".
```

The problem is that my first `AlertView` disappears directly and the method `didFailWithError` is the fist called. 
No 5 sec wait for first alert.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without code, but you could check if the following happens:
You display a view to which your 1st alert ("Please wait") has been added. Then you start a timer. While the timer runs, the program proceeds, and tries to load data from the web, which fails. This displays the 2nd alert on top of the 1st one, letting the 1st one "disappear".
The problem thus might be that `didFailWithError` is called before the timer could fire (I assume this would dismiss the 1st alert, right?).
My suggestion is that you check once more the logic of your app. I think it is reasonable to let the user know that he/she has to wait (1st alert), but waiting should be terminated (i.e. the 1st alert should be dismissed) either by a successful load of the data, or by an unsuccessful try (`didFailWithError`).
But what for is the timer? What to do if it fires before or while a successful download (an unsuccessful download could of course invalidate the timer)?